# What may be the reason why I get "Test ignored." message while running any test class in Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex

Tests ignored: 14, passed: 0
Whenever I run any test class I get this type of messages:

> Test ignored.
>
> Test method AccountAddressHelperTest.testInvalidBillingCountry was
> never reported as completed. Trigger.AllOppLineItemTriggers: line 188,
> column 31: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
> updateMISROnOpportunity(Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>,
> Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>) from the type OppLineItemHelper

Answer (score 0):

You have compilation failures. What happens if you hit Setup -> Classes -> Compile all?

You or your colleague edited something, probably in file OppLineItemHelper. Or some other file this file reuses. And now not everything compiles, dependencies aren't met. So best thing SF can do is skip these tests.

You can edit like that in sandboxes, SF will not always block you. But compile errors will prevent deployment to prod even before any tests are run